# Why http request error stops my application?

Tags: http, go, https

I do send requests via http client, however it stops after the first iteration. I do not see any panic, so do not understand what happens.

```
func sending() {
    var defaultTransport http.RoundTripper = &http.Transport{
        Proxy: nil,
        DialContext: (&net.Dialer{
            Timeout:   10 * time.Second,
            KeepAlive: 30 * time.Second,
        }).DialContext,
        MaxIdleConns:          30,
        IdleConnTimeout:       90 * time.Second,
        TLSHandshakeTimeout:   15 * time.Second,
        ExpectContinueTimeout: 1 * time.Second,
    }

    client := &http.Client{Transport: defaultTransport}

    var buf bytes.Buffer

    g := gzip.NewWriter(&buf)
    g.Write([]byte(messageToSend))
    g.Close()

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://xxxxxxxx.xxx/xxxxxxx", bytes.NewReader(buf.Bytes()))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Encoding", "gzip")

    println("request sent")

    resp, err := client.Do(req)

    println("response got")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } else {
        resp.Body.Close()

    }

}

func main() {

    for i:=1;i<10;i++{
        fmt.Println("Started",i)
        sending()
        fmt.Println("Finished",i)
    }

}
```

Log:

```
Started 1
request sent
2020/12/09 18:30:52 Unsolicited response received on idle HTTP channel starting with "\n"; err=<nil>
response got
2020/12/09 18:30:53 Post "https://xxxx.xxx/xxxx": net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: too many transfer encodings: ["chunked" "chunked"]
```

After this entry, the application stops and the next round is not executed.

Comment: Btw: Clients and Transports should be reused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`log.Fatal` closes the server as it says in the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#Fatal):

> Fatal is equivalent to Print() followed by a call to os.Exit(1).

Use `log.Print` instead if you just want to log the error.